# Move unallocated space so it can be assigned to an existing partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize, unallocated, merge

I have an issue that I cannot seem to solve, please see the following screenshot:

[image]

The circles represent the key symbols which aren't removed even during live session from a bootable USB of Xubuntu.

What I'm trying to achieve is to move the unallocated space all the way to the bottom so I can merge it with sda7.

I already tried all sorts of techniques of resizing and what not, it simply doesn't allow me to move that partition, it won't get past sda4.

Comment: I can't see the screenshot since the image sharing site is blocked by a campus firewall. Try imgur. That said, I assume you are talking of GParted here. You can right click the partition in GParted and click on *Unmount* to unmount the partition, after which you should be able to make changes.

Comment: @muru tried that also, didn't work. All I could change were flags.

Comment: No option to resize?

Comment: @muru even though I went through the live session the extended partition which holds /, swap and /home is locked and I can't unlock it.

Comment: @muru I've re-uploaded the image to Imgur.

Comment: Just to be certain, you can't unlock any partition within the extended partition? sda4 can't be unlocked if any partition within it is mounted. And on live session, the swap gets enabled, which would make sda6 and hence sda4 locked.

Comment: @muru I just checked and indeed unmounting swap enables me to move partitions and I did so, the only possible risk here is what Gparted warned me about, that moving the partition containing /boot at the start of the sector by moving the free space after it might cause the system not to boot.

Should this be the case re-assigning the /boot flag would help? Or re-installation of /.

Comment: The partitioning went smooth in the end, no errors, system loads, everything's running wonderful. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extended partition is locked whenever any logical partition within it is mounted. In a live session, swap gets automatically enabled, so the swap partition (in this case `sda6`) will be mounted. Hence `sda6` and consequently `sda4` become locked. To unlock an extended partition, you have to unmount the logical partitions within it by right clicking them and choosing *Unmount* (or *Swapoff* in the case of swap partitions).